# How to use regex to change occurance of complex strings?

Tags: regex, vb.net

For example,

Say I want to change
all occurances of `<img src="https://www.blahblah.com/i" title="Bob" />`

To simply

```
Bob
```

This is for vb.net

Basically there are plenty of such pattern in a big string. I want to change every one of them.

This is what I tried

```
Dim tdparking = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\w*       (<img.*title="")(.*)"" />")
```

After that I suppose I would need to do some substitution. But how?

How would I do so?

Comment: So you want to extract the content of the title attribute?

Comment: Yap. So I got a document and everytime I see that pattern I want to change that into the title attribute

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var str = '<img src="https://www.blahblah.com/i" title="Bob" />';
      str = str.replace(/<img[^>]*title="(\w+)"[^>]*>/,"$1");
  document.write(str);
```

Comment: str.replace can recoqnize regular expression?

Comment: @JimThio No, it's Javascript. You should probably tag your question as VB.NET since that what it looks like you're using. If you remove the leading and trailing `/`, then the pattern should work in .NET as well.

Comment: As Kenneth said it's javascript, and it's the regex:`<img[^>]*title="(\w+)"[^>]*>` , see [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY6rS2/1),and it should also worked in .net

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `\<img[^\<\>]+title=\"([a-zA-Z]+)\"[^\<\>]+\/\>` and return $1 of the matching pattern:

In PHP it should be:

```
preg_match_all('#\<img[^\<\>]+title=\"([a-zA-Z]+)\"[^\<\>]+\/\>#', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Regards,

Comment: I didn't mention that I want vb.net. Good answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is making this waay to hard - Here it is in vb.net

```
   Dim reg as Regex = New Regex("(?<=title="""").+(?="""")")
   Dim str as String = "<img src=""https://www.blahblah.com/i"" title=""Bob"" />"
   Dim match as String = reg.match(str).value
```

Depending on how the string is inputted you will either need

```
"(?<=title="""").+(?="""")" 'If there is Double quotes ("")
```

or

```
"(?<=title="").+(?="")" 'Or single quotes (")
```

Also there is no need for you to get downvoted - here is a point back